# Adjacency list representation of a weighted graph

Tags: c++, c++11

So guys, recently i have been practicing a lot with data structures, graphs and etc. And i encountered a problem with a given code. I am implementing a graph, that is represented with an adjacency list.The problem i stumble across is when i try to implement the solution, using user input. I have tried to do it in many ways but i still stumble across some problems in the program. Because i am using a vector that takes a list of integers, whenever i try to fill the vector with a while loop(for instance) i don't know why, but i can't quite fill it up correctly. And since my mistake starts even from there i don't know how to proceed with the program. If you guys can give me some sort of hint on how i can implement my code to work with user input, or even give me a similar code that i work with i would be really grateful !

This is my code:

```
const int N = 4;

//purpose of the class is to tell what the weight of the given edge is
class Edge{
   private:
       double weight;
       int vertex_id;

   public:
    //constructor that initializes the weight and vertex id

    Edge(double w, int id)
    {
        weight = w;
       vertex_id = id;
    }

    double getWeight() const
        {
            return weight;
        }

    int getId() const
    {
        return vertex_id;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::list<Edge>> adjList(N); //creating our vector that will store a list of integers

    adjList[0].push_back(Edge(4,1)); //pushing back the first neighbours of our Zero list
    adjList[0].push_back(Edge(2,2)); //pushing back the second neighbours of our Zero list and so on...

    adjList[1].push_back(Edge(4,0));
    adjList[1].push_back(Edge(5,2));

    adjList[2].push_back(Edge(2,0));
    adjList[2].push_back(Edge(5,1));
    adjList[2].push_back(Edge(1,3));

    adjList[3].push_back(Edge(1,2));

    std::vector<std::list<Edge>>::iterator i; //declaring our vector iterator

    int c = 0; //we create a counter(and ofcourse assign zero to it)


    //create the for loop, where the iterator starts at the begining of the vector
    //and ends when the vector (adjList) ends


    //*KEEP IN MIND THAT THE FIRST FOR LOOP ONLY ITERATES THROUGH THE NODES OF THE VECTOR
    for (std::vector<std::list<Edge>>::iterator i = adjList.begin(); i != adjList.end(); i++)
    {

        cout << "Vertices connected to our node: " << c << endl;
        std::list<Edge> li = *i; //this pointer serves the purpose to get the list for each different node

        //NOW THE SECOND FOR LOOP ITERATES THROUGH THE LISTS, THAT EACH NODE CONTAINS
        for (std::list<Edge>::iterator iter = li.begin(); iter != li.end(); iter++)
        {
            cout << " (V = " << (*iter).getId() << " weight= " << (*iter).getWeight() <<")";
        }

        cout << endl; // we end the line between the different nodes of the vector

        c++; //increment our counter
    }
```

Comment: `std::list<Edge> li = *i` makes a copy of the list, disconnected from the entry in `adjList`. You should take a reference instead: `std::list<Edge> & li = *i`

Comment: Also, you don't have to type out all the types of your iterators, C++11 can infer types from expressions, so `auto iter = li.begin()`

Comment: thank you very much for the corrections my friends, i will surely keep this information in mind in further implementation of my codes :)

Comment: @Somerandomguy: "So guys", "you guys" assumes that all the members are male.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach is to ask for the number of edges up front and then read that many space-separated triples of numbers in the format `from to weight`.
This can be as simple as:

```
int num_edges;
cin >> num_edges;
for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; i++) {
    int from, to, weight;
    cin >> from >> to >> weight;
    adjList[from].push_back(Edge(to, weight));
    // Uncomment this if you want an undirected graph
    // adjList[to].push_back(Edge(from, weight));
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, i will check it in a couple of hours !

Comment: i don't know why, but for some reason i just can't figure out how to print the numbers..

Comment: Print which numbers?

Comment: Ah sorry, not the numbers, rather how the list looks like after the insertions from the user

Comment: `for (int from = 0; from < adjList.size(); from++) { for (const Edge& e : adjList[i]) { cout << "edge from " << from << " to " << e.getId() << endl; } }`

Comment: thank you very much for the help my friend. i feel stupid to disturb you so much about this task.. but i don't quite get the output. For instance if i enter the number of edges to be 2. and then the input of from-to and weight is : 0 1 3, 
then the output is the following: edge from 0 to 3 , weight 1
edge from 1 to 3, weight 1. So it's kinda outputting correctly but not that good and i can't find anything wrong with the code..

Comment: Oh, i accidentally swapped the arguments to the `Edge` constructor. `weight` comes first.